# When does $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ preserve a linear order?

Tags: lo.logic, topological-groups, order-theory, automorphism-groups, algebraic-systems

I have a general-type question: 
Let $M$ be a countable structure that is ultrahomogeneous, i.e. every (partial) isomorphism between finitely generated substructures of $M$ extends to an automorphism of $M$. Also, let $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ be the group of automorphisms of $M$ equipped with the pointwise convergence topology.

I want to know necessary and/or sufficient conditions under which $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ preserves a linear ordering on $\mathbb{N}$, in the sense that $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ preserves $(\mathbb{N},\prec)$ iff for every $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and for every $g\in \operatorname{Aut}(M)$, $$n\prec m\Leftrightarrow g(n)\prec g(m).$$

Comment: Conditions on $M$ or conditions on $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$? A necessary condition is that $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Are you assuming that there already is a definable ordering in your setup and asking for conditions to have an infinite ascending chain, or are you asking about situations where you can prove that there is such a definable ordering?

Comment: If you're interested in the usual ordering on $\mathbb N$, not a general one, then that happens if and only if, for each element, there is a formula that uniquely picks it out.

Comment: My reading of the question is whether there exists a linear order $\prec$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(M)=\mathrm{Aut}(M,\prec)$. The order is not assumed to have an infinite ascending chain (though this can be trivially arranged by inverting the order, if necessary), and it is not assumed definable (because then it is trivially preserved by the automorphism group). For example, $M=(\mathbb N,0,s)$ has trivial automorphism group, hence it preserves the usual order on $\mathbb N$ (or any other relation on $\mathbb N$, for that matter), but no infinite linear order is definable in $M$. 

Comment: Emil Jerabek's comment is on the point: We are not assuming that $M$ is equipped with any linear order ($\prec$ or anything else). The question has to do with $Aut(M)$ preserving a linear order $\prec$ on $\mathbb{N}$. 

Of course, if such an ordering exists and we identify the universe of $M$ with the natural numbers, then $Aut(M)=Aut(M,\prec)$.

Comment: @Will: I don’t think so. Let $M$ be $\mathbb Z$ (as a set) with all unary predicates of the form $x\equiv a\pmod b$ for natural numbers $0\le a< b$. Then every two elements of $M$ are distinguishable by an atomic formula, hence $M$ is ultrahomogeneous with a trivial automorphism group (in particular, it preserves whatever you please), but no element of $M$ is definable (because every reduct of $M$ to a finite language has a nontrivial automorphism, namely a suitable shift).

Comment: @Emil: That is correct. What is true, I guess, is that preserving the traditional order on $\mathbb N$ implies trivial automorphism group.

Comment: @ Emil: Can you explain why torsion-free $Aut(M)$ is necessary?

Comment: Even more generally, if $g\in\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ and $a\in M$ are such that $g^n(a)=a$ for some $n>0$, then $g(a)=a$. If not, then WLOG $a\prec g(a)$. Since $g$ preserves $\prec$, we have $g^k(a)\prec g^{k+1}(a)$ for every $k< n$, which gives $a\prec g^n(a)=a$ by transitivity, a contradiction.

Comment: For a closed subgroup $G\le S_\omega$, one has the obvious implications: $G$ preserves a total order $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is left-orderable $\Rightarrow$ $G$ is torsion-free. Examples with $G$ discrete show that the converse is false in general. With the additional assumption that $G$ is the automorphism group of a ultrahomogeneous structure on $\omega$, I don't know counterexamples to the reverse implications.